# Can not add view programmatically in a constraint layout

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to add views with Java code in my android application but even a basic test Textviews won't show

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.form1);

    TextView mazzo = new TextView(this);
    mazzo.setId(View.generateViewId());
    mazzo.setText(m_Text);
    mazzo.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.addView(mazzo);

    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

    set.clone(layout);
    set.connect(mazzo.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 18);
    set.connect(mazzo.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 18);
    set.applyTo(layout);
```

Comment: You textview needs to be constrained in its parent. You are not specifying any constraints.

Comment: added the connect, still doesnt works

Comment: your code works perfectly for me even without the constraints. Maybe, check whether the m_Text is empty or null.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out, i had another contraint layout as my main and apparently if u put another constraint layout inside u have to connect every single side or it wont show so after connecting right and bottom too it worked.